# show div if one of the speciefied value selected in multiple select

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3, visible

Here i want the div to be shown if the specified value is present or selected and the div should be hide if the specified value is not selected.
here is my code

```
<select name="result" id="result"  class="form-control select2" style="width: 70%" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="q">Q</option> 
</select>
```

here is html

```
<div class="form-group" id="qaranty_count_full">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Count:</label>
    <input type="number" required name="qaranty_count" class="form-control"  id="qaranty_count" value="1">
 </div>
```

Here is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#qaranty_count_full').hide();
   $("#result").change(function(){
   if($('option:selected', this).val()=='q')
   {

     $('#qaranty_count_full').show();
     $('#qaranty_count').prop('required', true);
   }
   else
   {
     $('#qaranty_count_full').hide();
     $('#qaranty_count').prop('required', false);
   }

 });
});
</script>
```

in this case if i choose `q` first time the `div` becomes visible and if i choose `q` as second or third value the `div` is not becoming visible,the div should remain visible if `q` is selected,hope understood my problem

Comment: Please add div HTML too

Comment: I think you need to do comparision through array as it's comparing single value , but not multiple. Also if you can set up fiddle would be great to test same.

Comment: @LGSon works if only `q` value is present but multiple values selected `div` becomes invisible

Comment: Check my answer below. @user_777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#result").change(function(){
     if($.inArray("q", $(this).val()) !== -1){
        $('#qaranty_count_full').show();
        $('#qaranty_count').prop('required', true);
     }else{
        $('#qaranty_count_full').hide();
        $('#qaranty_count').prop('required', false);
      }
 });
});
```

Here is a codepen I have created.

https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/BrpPPN

Comment: Here is updated codepen with complete solution https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzRKPo

Comment: Welcome bro @user_777 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this, using `.each`, and loop the selected array.

Stack snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="result" id="result"  class="form-control select2" style="width: 70%" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="q">Q</option> 
</select>

<div class="form-group" id="qaranty_count_full">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Count:</label>
    <input type="number" required name="qaranty_count" class="form-control"  id="qaranty_count" value="1">
 </div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#qaranty_count_full').hide();
   $("#result").change(function(){

     $('#qaranty_count_full').hide();
     $('#qaranty_count').prop('required', false);
     
     $('option:selected', this).each(function(i,sel){     
       if ($(sel).val() == 'q') {
         $('#qaranty_count_full').show();
         $('#qaranty_count').prop('required', true);
       }
     });
 });
});
</script>
```